# PouchDB: no conflict

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, iriscouch

I use PouchDB to save user data from a website to CouchDB (on IrisCouch). Following a mistake, I pushed documents with already taken names. I tried to recover the conflicting files admitting that there was a conflict.

```
db.get('threshold0_1_3', {conflicts: true}).then(function (doc) {
  console.log(doc, doc._conflicts);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

But the `doc._conflicts` is null and the document don't have a "_conflicts" property.

So I tried to create a conflict with this code:

```
var db = new PouchDB("http://127.0.0.1:5984/test");
var data = {"_id": "testDoc", "count": 1};

db.put(data).then(function (response) {
  // handle response
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

// modify document
data = {"_id": "testDoc", "count": 2};

db.put(data).then(function (response) {
  // handle response
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

// Output
o {status: 409, name: "conflict", message: "Document update conflict", error: true, reason: "Document update conflict."}

// Check if the doc contains ._conflicts
db.get('testDoc', {conflicts: true}).then(function (doc) {
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(doc._conflicts);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});

// Output:
Object {_id: "testDoc", _rev: "1-74620ecf527d29daaab9c2b465fbce66", count: 1}
undefined
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 409 indicates that the `put()` was rejected because it *would* have created a conflict. To manually create conflicts (if you really want to), you would need to `put()` the same document twice in two different databases, and then replicate them.  Here's an example script.

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

var db1 = new PouchDB('foo');
var db2 = new PouchDB('bar');

db1.put({_id: 'doc'}).then(function () {
  return db2.put({_id: 'doc'});
}).then(function () {
  return db1.sync(db2);
}).then(function () {
  return db1.get('doc', {conflicts: true});
}).then(function (doc) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
}).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

This prints out:

```
{"_id":"doc","_rev":"1-94c8f741dd8ab2a80ff49b1335e805fb","_conflicts":["1-2e0e51eeaf0d9d67b8293f205b8e4a0c"]}
```

Comment: Thanks! So when there is a 409 data is not stored. I imagine that it is impossible to recover it?

Comment: That's why it gives you a 409, yes, so you can work around it. You might also look into the pouchdb-upsert plugin if you want to avoid 409s.